# Single Multi-label classifier or multiple single-label classifiers?

Tags: classification, multilabel

I have a problem to classify my data that can fit into more than one class at same time. Based on an initial study, I came across "Multi-label classifier" that can classify data into more than one class simultaneously. Or as its internal implementation goes, I can have multiple single-label classifiers.

I'm fairly new to this domain and have been dealing with single-label classifiers till now. Can someone suggest me which way to opt for based on ease-of-implementation, any reusable existing libraries.